# Name for a product of actions / dynamical systems

Tags: reference-request, ds.dynamical-systems, terminology, group-actions

Suppose $G \curvearrowright X, H \curvearrowright Y$ are group (or monoid) actions, or dynamical systems. Then $X \times Y$ is a $G \times H$-system of the same type in the obvious way by $(g, h) \cdot (x, y) = (g \cdot x, h \cdot y)$.

> Question. Does this have a standard name?

I couldn't find a term in the dynamical systems literature, though I think it is not that rare a construction. Of course it can be called just the direct product, but the issue is that if $G = H$, then this can very easily be confused with the diagonal product, which especially in dynamics is *much* more common.

This is very categorical, my naive thinking is as follows: For a monoid $M$, $M$-systems are just functors from $M$ (seen as a category) to your favorite category $\mathcal{C}$. Now the diagonal product is just taking two functors $F, G : M \to \mathcal{C}$ and combining them to a functor $F \times G : M \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$. And now when $\mathcal{C}$ is a monoidal category you can see objects of $\mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$ as living in $\mathcal{C}$. (In most of my categories of interest the monoidal product is simply a literal Cartesian product, I don't know if in general there are issues with this picture.) For group representations I think both the the direct and tensor products correspond to this construction, and they differ in which monoidal structure you take for vector spaces, i.e. whether you use direct product or tensor product there.

Now, the product I define takes instead functors $F : M \to \mathcal{C}$ and $G : N \to \mathcal{C}$, and combines them to $F \times G : M \times N \to \mathcal{C} \times \mathcal{C}$, and again we think of the codomains as objects in $\mathcal{C}$ by using the monoidal product. Of course the category $M \times N$ is itself a monoid, and we get an $M \times N$-action.

Another angle is that maybe the box product in graph theory is analogous.

Comment: I'd be tempted to call it the **external product** and denote it by $X \boxtimes Y$. But I don't know whether that's standard.

Comment: Can you expound on that? I found the Wikipedia page for this term in algebra, but I'm not making a connection.